# for multiindex for columns calculate min/max of columns that share the same name for level=1

Tags: python, pandas

Good day,
For the following dataframe with MultiIndex for columns

```
      1    |    2   |     level = 1
--------------------
   a |  b | a | b |   level = 0
------------------
0  1     2    3   1  
1  2     5    6   4
2  85    74   5   92
```

I am trying to caclulate min and max of columns for level = 1 (max/min of columns a and b for column 1 and max/min of columns a and b for column 2), but have not find the decent way to do it.

I would like to have something like this:

```
        1    |    2   |     level = 1
-----------------------
      a |  b | a | b  |   level = 0
-----------------------
min    1         1
max    85        92
```

Could you help me and share your ideas please.

Comment: Your input should only have 1 level as you aggregate, also you're inverting the level numbers: the top one is 0, bottom is 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) the unused level (1, not 0!) and [`agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html):

```
out = df.stack().agg(['min', 'max'])
```

Output:

```
      1   2
min   1   1
max  85  92
```

Reproducible input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,1],[2,5,6,4],[85,74,5,92]],
                 columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[1, 2], ['a', 'b']])
                 )
```